# Excel: How to use result of one function as the parameter/range for a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 formulas that work fine independently, once I combine then I plan to stick them into an If formula and get the result I want. However, I don't know how to use the result of the first formula as the Range parameter for the second.

1st: `=MATCH(B3,'Sheet1'!A1:A18,0)` returns 8

2nd: `=COUNTIF(‘Sheet1’!8:8,V1)>0` returns true

Instead of typing `8:8` like I did in the 2nd formula, I want my MATCH, which returns 8, to do that instead.

`=COUNTIF('Sheet1'!MATCH(B3,'Sheet1'!A1:A18,0):MATCH(B3,'PSR Training Schedule'!A1:A18,0),V1)>0` doesn't work.

I'm pretty sure my formatting is wrong but I don't know what what I'm looking for called to even begin to look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(Sheet1!1:1040000,MATCH(B3,Sheet1!A1:A18,0),0),V1)>0
```

the `INDEX(Sheet1!1:1040000,MATCH(B3,Sheet1!A1:A18,0),0)` returns the whole row where the match is found in column A

Comment: It says I have too many arguments. I want the MATCH to be the range of Sheet 1, not the criteria of the COUNTIF. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Sorry had a typo, forgot the INDEX.  See edit @Mofongo

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'PSR Training Schedule'!"&MATCH(B3,Sheet1!A1:A18,0)&":"&MATCH(B3,Sheet1!A1:A18,0)),V1)>0
```

**Edit**:

A slightly more efficient version with error handling could be this:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(V1,INDIRECT("'PSR Training Schedule'!"&MATCH(B3,Sheet1!A1:A18,0)&":"&MATCH(B3,Sheet1!A1:A18,0)),0))
```

...since `COUNTIF` 'counts' all occurrences, while `MATCH` 'matches' only one.

**The Logic**

Using `MATCH` we are getting the position (row) of the value of `B3` in the range of `Sheet1!A1:A18`. This position we are going to use as the row in `PSR Training Schedule` where to find the value from `V1`. `B3` & `V1` are in the same worksheet, which could be a third worksheet.

Comment: one note to the OP and future readers, INDIRECT is a volatile function that, if used in excess, will slow down Excel as each one will reclalc every time there is any change anywhere in the app.  used sparingly it is not a problem.

Comment: BTW it was not me that downvoted.  Just to clarify.

Comment: Thx. I know that: why would you bother commenting. As you can note my lack of knowledge in Excel, you or some other ace in `Excel Formula` should consider this as a blueprint to write a better solution; if my logic is right, of course. Well, we didn't ask OP a lot of questions.

Comment: I comment for future readers so they know the cost of using volatile functions.  The goal of this site is to create repository of information.  Your answer is not bad, like I said I did not down vote.  There is just a cost to it.  And I did `write a better solution`.  It does not use volatile functions and does what the OP is wanting.  Again I would not have been upset or hurt if your answer was the one the OP decided was the "correct" answer.  I just wanted future lookers that do not know the cost of Volatile function to learn.  If you put that caveat in the answer, I will remove the comment.